# why doesn't this synchronized method work as expected?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a class called "Account"

```
public class Account {

    public double balance = 1500;

    public synchronized double withDrawFromPrivateBalance(double a) {
        balance -= a;
        return balance;
    }
}
```

and a class called ATMThread

```
public class ATMThread extends Thread {
    double localBalance = 0;
    Account myTargetAccount;

    public ATMThread(Account a) {
        this.myTargetAccount = a;
    }

    public void run() {
        find();
    }

    private synchronized void find() {
        localBalance = myTargetAccount.balance;
        System.out.println(getName() + ": local balance = " + localBalance);
        localBalance -= 100;
        myTargetAccount.balance =  localBalance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account();
        System.out.println("START: Account balance = " + account.balance);

        ATMThread a = new ATMThread(account);
        ATMThread b = new ATMThread(account);

        a.start();
        b.start();

        try {
            a.join();
            b.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("END: Account balance = " + account.balance);
    }

}
```

I create two threads, we assume there is an initial balance in the bank account(1500$)

the first thread tries to withdraw 100$ and the second thread as well.

I expect the final balance to be 1300, however it is sometimes 1400. Can someone explain me why? I'm using synchronized methods...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This method is correct and should be used:

```
public synchronized double withDrawFromPrivateBalance(double a)
{
          balance -= a;
          return balance;
}
```

It correctly restricts access to the account internal state to only one thread at a time. However your `balance` field is `public` (so not really internal), which is the root cause of all your problems:

```
public double balance = 1500;
```

Taking advantage of `public` modifier you are accessing it from two threads:

```
private synchronized void find(){
    localBalance = myTargetAccount.balance;
    System.out.println(getName() + ": local balance = " + localBalance);
    localBalance -= 100;
    myTargetAccount.balance =  localBalance;
}
```

This method, even though looks correct with `synchronized` keyword, it is not. You are creating two threads and `synchronized` thread is basically a lock tied to an object. This means these two threads have separate locks and each can access its own lock.

Think about your `withDrawFromPrivateBalance()` method. If you have two instances of `Account` class it is safe to call that method from two threads on two different objects. However you cannot call `withDrawFromPrivateBalance()` on the same object from more than one thread due to `synchronized` keyword. This is sort-of similar.

You can fix it in two ways: either use `withDrawFromPrivateBalance()` directly (note that `synchronized` is no longer needed here):

```
private void find(){
    myTargetAccount.withDrawFromPrivateBalance(100);
}
```

or lock on the same object in both threads as opposed to locking on two independent `Thread` object instances:

```
private void find(){
    synchronized(myTargetAccount) {
      localBalance = myTargetAccount.balance;
      System.out.println(getName() + ": local balance = " + localBalance);
      localBalance -= 100;
      myTargetAccount.balance =  localBalance;
    }
}
```

The latter solution is obviously inferior to the former one because it is easy to forget about external synchronization somewhere. Also you should never use public fields.

Answer (score 9):

Your `private synchronized void find()` method is synchronizing on different locks. Try synchronizing it on same objects like

```
private void find(){
    synchronized(myTargetAccount){
        localBalance = myTargetAccount.balance;
        System.out.println(getName() + ": local balance = " + localBalance);
        localBalance -= 100;
        myTargetAccount.balance =  localBalance;
    }
}
```

You can also make your Account class more thread safe, by making its fields private and adding `synchronized` modifier to **all** its getters and setters and then **use only this methods** to change value of fields.

Answer (score 4):

Marking a method synchronized obtains a lock on the object that the method is being run on, but there are two different objects here: the `ATMThread` and the `Account`.

In any event, the two different `ATMThread`s are using *different* locks, so their writes can overlap and conflict with one another.

Instead, you should have both `ATMThread`s synchronize on the *same* object.