# Why is Java synchronized not working as expected?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm trying to figure out how synchronized methods work. From my understanding I created two threads **T1** and **T2** that will call the same method `addNew`, since the method is synchronized shouldn't it execute all the iterations of the for loop for one thread and then the other? The output keeps varying, sometimes it prints it right, other times it prints values from T1 mixed with T2 values. The code is very simple, can someone point out what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new A());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new A());
        t1.setName("T1");
        t2.setName("T2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

public class B {
    public synchronized void addNew(int i){
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.println(t.getName() +"-"+(j+i));
        }
    }
}

public class A extends Thread {
    private B b1 = new B();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        b1.addNew(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: You synchronize with different instances of `B`

Comment: `A` both extends `Thread` and is passed to a `Thread` constructor. That should not be. Don't extend `Thread`, extend `Runnable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why doesn't this synchronized method work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073841/why-doesnt-this-synchronized-method-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each `A` instance has its own `B` instance.  The method `addNew` is an instance method of `B`.  Therefore, the lock acquired implicitly during calls to `addNew` is the lock on the receiver `B` instance.  Each thread is calling `addNew` on a different `B`, and therefore locking on different locks.

If you want *all* `B` instances to use a common lock, create a single shared lock, and acquire it in the body of `addNew`.

Comment: Thank you, how would I go about creating a single shared lock?

Comment: Every object can act as a lock, so just make one that is shared across all instances of `B`.  `private static final Object lock = new Object()`.

Comment: Or pass the same `Runnable` instance to each thread, which is frequently done.

Answer (score 3):

Both `A` objects have their own `B` object. You need them to share a `B` so the synchronization can have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(a);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(a);
        t1.setName("T1");
        t2.setName("T2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

 class B {
    public synchronized void addNew(int i){
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.println(t.getName() +"-"+(j+i));
        }
    }
}

 class A extends Thread {
    private B b1 = new B();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        b1.addNew(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the explanation, that was asked for in the Question? Also, how does this change the execution? Please explain.

Comment: For synchronization, a thread needs to lock the object for it to execute completely.
When it completes synchronized code's execution, it kind of leaves the object and then that same object is locked by another thread and it executes,thus achieving synch. And for this to happen, same object has to be passed as arguement while creating Thread object. The post author creates Thread objects using "new A()" as arguemnet,that kind of, is passing two different objects. so synchronization is not achieved.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant for you to add it to your post :)